# multiple Lists in a ListActivity and onListItemClick feature (or workaround?)

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onclick, listactivity

I know that `ListActivity` gives me the possibility to use `onListItemClick`.
On the other hand in a normal `Activity` i can include multiple lists and make easy switching+animation through a `ViewFlipper`.

So. Can i make it work alltogether?

**[Solved]** Yes! ... implements are the kings. Deleted my code to minimize confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried having your Activity implement OnItemClickListener and then set your lists' onItemClickListener to the activity? I.e.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    ...
    public void onCreate(...) {
        ...
        mList1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        mList2.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        ...
    }
    ...
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) {
       if (adapter.getId() == R.id.list1) {
           // Handle list1 click event
       } else if (adapter.getId() == R.id.list2) {
           // Handle list2 click event
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Just tried, but a simple Toast-message when im clicking the listitem doesn't appear. I'll add some code above to clarify.

Comment: I think I mixed up view and adapter. It should be the id of the adapter you are checking, not the View. The View object being passed in is the View of the row, not the ListView. I will update the code above to reflect the change.

Comment: Yeah. It works now. It was really the adapter. Thank you very much!